# Prevent multiple threads/instances to select and process the same rows in Azure SQL-database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have a question regarding how to prevent multiple instances of an application and/or threads from selecting the same rows within an MSSQL table.

This is the scenario:
I have an ASP.net site where users will be able to enter their email.
The email will then be inserted into a table within my MSSQL Database.

Then the idea is to have a WebJob(Azure WebJob) that once every five second selects all newly created rows and then sends an email to each user and then flags the row as "processed"..

However.. 
What if I for some reason decide to scale my WebJob into multiple instances?..
I assume that there might be a smal window where multiple instances might select the same rows within the database and then process the rows and send multiple emails to the registered user?
Is there someway to sort of "lock" the rows thats currently in process by another instance/thread?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Br,
Inx

Comment: Take a look at [service bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/service-bus/). I think it is better than using SQL database for you case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on ASP.Net as it's been ages since I've done anything with it. But with SQL Server you should look into data queue examples. The link below is a good place to start:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/

You can use query hints (ie. UPDLOCK, READPAST as in the link) and constraints (enforce uniqueness etc) to make sure that no two threads can ever read or write the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather integrate the sending of the mail into the same process as inserting into the db etc. For example, you could have a stored procedure that inserts the new record into the database and then sends a mail using sp_send_dbmail.

You could also make use of SQL Dependency. If you enable the broker in SQL Server and make use of SQL Dependency, then any changes to the database will be pushed to your app. SQL Dependency is quite easy to use, a bit of googling and you will find many tutorials.

In both of these solutions, you would not need to be continuously polling your database.

If you have to use the webjobs then you can wrap your code in `TransactionScope` with `Serialized` isolation level. This will prevent problems with multiple instances.

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
 {
      /* Perform transactional work here */
      SomeMethod();
      scope.Complete();
 }
```

I believe that when using TransactionScope the isolation level is set to serializable by default.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, to send the email directly using the same thread/instance would make alot of sense, however the systems current architecture requires the emails to be "queued".
Also since the application and the database will be hosted in Azure(Web App,WebJob and Azure SQL) I wont be able to use the SQL Dependency.. and sorry for a quite miss-guiding topic title.. I will change from MSSQL to Azure SQL.